# setString is Depreciated in Hibernate. What is the other Alternative?

Tags: hibernate

I am using the following code to retrieve content form objects using hibernate, and i use setString to assign query value .

```
try
        {
            //sql injections prevented using setString(position,value)
             List<Student> studentList=session.createQuery("from Student s where s.lastName=?")
                                              .setString(0,lname).list();
             for(Student studentinfo:studentList)
             {
                 System.out.println(studentinfo);
             }
             model.addAttribute("result",studentList);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Everything work well. but the IDE Shows that setString method is depreciated.
What is the other alternative of setString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Hibernate 5.2+. The [Official document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-) says you should use [setParameter(int position, java.lang.Object val)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/query/Query.html#setParameter-int-java.lang.Object-) instead to set the query parameters.

To evade the warning, you can simply replace `setString` with `setParamter` like below.

```
List<Student> studentList=session.createQuery("from Student s where s.lastName=?")
                                          .setParamter(0,lname).list();
```